# How to retrieve information from a record in a database in PHP 5.5?

Tags: php, mysql

I am mostly confused about the new php 5.5, I apologize for any inconvenience.

I am trying to get information from whomever logs in, so for example if I log in with an email, I'd like the website to get my first name and do a "Welcome, Shinji!".

```
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
    $db = mysqli_select_db($conn , 'session_start');

    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    $query = mysqli_query($conn , "SELECT * FROM `info_table` WHERE '$user' = `user` AND '$pass'=`password`") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if($rows == 1){

        #$query2 = mysqli_query($conn , "INSERT INTO `who_logged` (`name`) VALUES ('$user')") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        #$rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

        session_start();

         $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['user']; // store username
         $_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['pass']; // store password

        $query2 = mysqli_query($conn ,"SELECT `name` FROM `info_table` WHERE '$user' = `user`") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        $result = mysqli_num_rows($query2);

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];//I thought to try setting the name to the Session variable, but does not work
    }

        header('Location: next_page.php');
        exit();

    }else{
        echo "Wrong username or password.";
    }
```

I tried to set the name to a session variable, but if there is a more efficient way please say so! (This current code works, except the name setting to session.

Comment: You're using the wrong identifiers around your column(s) and values, including mixing MySQL APIs. Plus, you need to invert what you're using. `$pass` and `password` etc.

Comment: You're vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: I was writing up an answer, but at this point, I have changed my mind.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, pls don't eat my points :)

Comment: @Rahul It's all yours Rahul ;) I'm skipping this one out. You'll have to retype it lol

Comment: @Fred-ii-, LOL .. just kidding .. I am no way interested writing an answer for this question. If someone must then that should be you since you have pointed that first.

Comment: @Rahul I'm just unsure about `while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))` which I know should be `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))` with the added `i`, however, when an OP says "it works..." and with what is posted, nope... not touching this with a 10 foot pole.

Comment: Is this what the community can bring to those who are learning?

Comment: I know it is a bad code, I am only just learning. If you have some remarks go ahead, But i hardly understand the need to be insulting @fred-ii. People like you might as well leave the world of learning to those who have the heart for it. Thank you.

Comment: I hardly think I was insulting. I said I wasn't touching this. Your code is unsure and I am afraid it will only open up something bigger and that I will only be commenting back and forth with an "answer". I've given you enough information to fix it yourself.

Comment: My remark applies to @patrick Q as well.

Comment: Thank you for your kind input. I am not using this code for anything serious, it is only a test code. I build simple modules before the main one. Thank you again.

Comment: I will post the answer I was writing up earlier, but if it doesn't work, I will delete it.

Answer (score 4):

You have your column(s) and values mixed up in order.

It's column first, then the value and not the other way around.

Change both:

```
WHERE '$user' = `user` AND '$pass'=`password`
```

to:

```
WHERE `user` = '$user' AND `password`='$pass'
```

Plus, you're mixing MySQL APIs. Those different APIs do not intermix with each other.

Change `mysql_fetch_assoc` to `mysqli_fetch_assoc`

I noticed you are using sessions; make sure `session_start();` is indeed loaded.

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Also, add `or die(mysqli_error($conn))` to `mysqli_query()`

---

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/).
Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

---

**EDIT:**

Try the following instead and it will get you started. Please read my **footnotes** concerning the use/storage of plain text passwords.

Sidenote: I removed `$_SESSION['password'] = $pass; // store password`
**do not do this,** it's insecure.

Plus, do not put anything "above" the PHP below, such as HTML etc., otherwise, you will receive a warning about headers already sent.

```
<?php 
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
$db = mysqli_select_db($conn, 'session_start');

$user = stripslashes($_POST['user']);
$user = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['user']);

$pass = stripslashes($_POST['pass']);
$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['pass']);

$query = mysqli_query($conn , "SELECT * FROM `info_table` 

    WHERE `user` = '$user' AND `password`='$pass'") 

        or die(mysqli_error($conn));

$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if($num_rows > 0){

    session_start();

    // it's not really needed
    // we are pulling it from $row['user'] in the while loop
    // and setting it to $_SESSION['username']
    // $_SESSION['username'] = $user; // store username

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['user'];
    }

    // for testing only. Do not use with header
    //  echo $_SESSION['username'];

    header('Location: next_page.php');
    exit();
}

// do not place any echos here, only the else statement

else{
    echo "Wrong username or password.";
}
```

**next_page.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){

    echo $_SESSION['username'];
}

else{

    echo "Not logged in.";

}
```

---

**Footnotes**

It is highly recommended that you do not store passwords in plain text.

Visit the following Website:

- **http://daveismyname.com/login-and-registration-system-with-php-bp**

It contains a full registration/login/verification system as well as using [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) and PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function, which is highly recommended.

- Since you are using PHP 5.5, then you will benefit from these features.

Comment: Thank you fred. This has set me on the right direction. I doubt my query works, so I will try to rewrite it differently. I apologize for being rude as well.

Comment: @Shinji You're quite welcome. Please reload my answer, I have included a few extras to check for errors. *Cheers*

Comment: @Shinji Reload my answer and look under **EDIT** near the bottom. Plus, it contains more information about security/links.